# the main startup class is not vaild, main method is missing

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, execute

As you can see in the title when I try to execute my program to .exe and run it I get this error (the main startup class is not valid, main method is missing)... which is obvious that the main method is missing, but the problem is it is not... I have the main method inside the main class and I can open the program from Intellij idea fine, but just when I execute it this error appears... and there was no such an error like this in the internet when I googled it so is there anyone have any idea about the problem ?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static Stage stage = new Stage();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view/login.fxml"));
        stage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 822, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: `I try to execute my program to .exe` - this statement needs clarification. How exactly did you run this code? Also post actual error text here.

Comment: You're calling `launch(String[] args)` method, where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you setup your artifacts to build your `.jar` file, you've forgotten to point to the Main class.

Go to your `Project Structure` window (`File` > `Project Structure`).

Then to the `Artifacts` tab.

Then click the `+` icon on the top left and click `JAR` then `From modules with dependencies`.

Then on the `Main class` field, click the folder icon on the right, then select your `Main` class.

Then press `OK` three times.

Here is a gif showing the steps in `Project Structure` window:

[image]

Afterwards, click `Build` menu on the top.

Then click `Build Artifacts` then click Build next to the artifact you created.

Here is a gif showing the process and where you can expect the `.jar` file to end up in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the beautiful explanation but I did exactly the same in your gifs and when I run the jar program it says the same error .... after hours and hours of testing and trying and searching I found the mistake which is  ` public static Stage stage = new Stage(); ` when I removed it and built the program I run the jar and it worked .... I have no idea what is the problem but I solved it when I removed that line.